# jquery get href value and use it as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

So I have set up a scrolling code for my website.

```
<section class="fpage">
   <a class="next" href="#view">test</a>
</section>

<section class="cpage">test</section>
```

In jquery I've got.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.next').click(function (event) {
        var cpage = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        var fpage = $(this).closest('section');
        event.preventDefault();

        fpage.addClass('anim').delay(500).queue(function(next){
            $(this).removeClass().addClass('cpage');
            next();
            cpage.removeClass('.cpage').addClass('fpage');
        });
    });
});
```

I want the `var`:`cpage` to take the `.next` `href` value (in this case: #view) and use it as the name of it's variable.  What have I dont wrong in this instance?  And how can I turn the cpage `var` into #view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.next` is the `a` itself. you don't need to use `.find`

```
  var cpage = $(this).attr('href');
```

OR

```
  var cpage = this.href;
```

Edit : *as `cpage` is an ID you need to do this to select the element*

```
 $(cpage).removeClass('.cpage').addClass('fpage');
```

Comment: hmm... I've done this and the code still doesn't seem to work.  The first part of my code works, the first section is getting the addClass but then the second part doesn't (where cpage.removeClass begins)

Comment: @David  as `cpage` is an ID you need to do this to select the element `-->`  `$(cpage).removeClass('.cpage').addClass('fpage');`

Comment: Yep, that worked!  **Thanks a ton!**  Will accept that answer as soon as StackOverflow lets me!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, this should solve:

```
fpage.addClass('anim').delay(500).queue(function(next){
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('cpage');
    next();
    $(cpage).removeClass('.cpage').addClass('fpage');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things out of place but all in all, no biggie.

First,

```
$('.next').click(function (event) {
    var cpage = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
```

It can't call its self. `.next` is a class for the a tag, so how can a tag find inner elements with the a tag if it is the only a tag element? jQuery's `.find` works to find children and grandchildren and such of the element it's called upon. thus this line is just as easy written as:

```
var cpage = $(this).attr('href');
```

Second,

```
cpage.removeClass('.cpage').addClass('fpage');
```

`cpage` is only a string variable, not a jQuery object, thus it needs a slight change. Try:

```
$(cPage).removeClass
```

I don't know what version of jQuery you are using, but I gave your code a complete scrub down and edit and posted a jsFiddle using the latest jQuery's. Important to note, if you're using an older version, some things might be different, such as `.on` being `.bind` or `.live` in older versions.

## jsFiddle

```
$(function() {
    $(".next").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var cPage = $(this).attr("href"),
            fPage = $(this).closest("section");

        fPage.addClass("anim").delay(500).queue(function(n) {
            $(this).removeClass().addClass('cpage');
            n();
            $(cPage).removeClass('.cpage').addClass('fpage');
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: thanks for that.  I'll update my code accordingly.  I'm actually a beginner, hence the really poorly written code... :)

Comment: @David Welcome aboard. If you'd like to see more examples of jQuery in action, you can check our my profile on here (where I've answered ALOT of jQuery questions) or see my [list of jsFiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/Q2R7P/) (where i have a ton of jQuery example usage and plugins)